# Connect Sonarqube 6.7 to external Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube, localhost, port, sonarqube-ops

I've been using Sonarqube with its embedded database for demos. Now, I need to connect it to an external Elasticsearch instance to meet the requirements of a production environment.

Which configurations I have to add on the `elasticsearch.yml` and `sonar.properties`?

Answer (score 5):

For the move to production, you don't need to, and shouldn't try to connect to an external Elasticsearch instance. SonarQube starts up and manages its own instance internally.

What you *do* need to do is connect to an external *database*, and that's easily done by setting the correct properties in *$SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties*

Comment: @ganncamp If I still wanted to use external elasticsearch with sonarqube 6.7, for achieving HA, is it possible?

Comment: @AshutoshBharti there's a commercial plugin that allows you to designate separate nodes for SQ's internal ElasticSearch. But even with the HA plugin the answer to using external ES is still 'no'.

Comment: Why though? ES runs very well as external cluster service?

Comment: In addition AWS supports ES as a service which is managed and backed up

Answer (score 1):

I succeed to use a external ElasticSearch with latest sonarqube 8.9. But it's just a hack at your own risk.

### Steps

#### Create a elastic search server

First start a elastic search instance anywhere.

#### Modify the config files

Modify the file

```
cat >> conf/sonar.properties < EOF
# your external host and port
sonar.search.port=9200
sonar.search.host=192.168.xx.xx
EOF
# create a dummy run script
cat > elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch << EOF
#!/bin/bash
# it's a inflate sleep
cat
EOF
```

#### Run sonarqube

just start sonarqube and view indexs in your new elasticsearch.